# What would constitute saatvik food for a person high in vaat?

Tags: food, gunas, ayurveda

If I am not mistaken what is considered to be *saatvik* food for one may not be for another. It depends on the degree of the following *doshas* in individual- *vata, pitta* and *kapha* .

As per Ayurveda, each of three energies (Vata, Pitta and Kapha) believed to circulate in the body govern physiological activity. Their proportions determine individual temperament and physical constitution. Is this true?

Can someone help explain the various tastes based on these three terms backed by scriptures ?

Assuming above is true, please advise what would be the food to avoid for a person high in vaat.